# Magmi url_key slug - how to include sku?

Tags: magento, url, magmi

I'm trying to figure out the best course of action to change URL keys in the store to be name-sku.html

Currently MAGMI seems to be dictating the url key, which is fine.  Some of our products are not imported through MAGMI, so I think I'd probably have to also use the updateurl event to change the url on save -- I found this here for that -- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24869/manufacturer-in-product-url-key

The question is, how is it best to do this within MAGMI?  I'm importing about 300,000 products currently.  The URL also needs to change, as it currently just uses the default settings.

I've looked into the wiki here -- http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Value_Replacer -- I guess the following code could work for the way it is currently working -- but what do I actually type into the value replacer box?

```
{{ Slugger::slug({item.name}) }}
```

Does anyone know how to add the sku to this as well?  Would I just do something like....

```
{{ Slugger::slug({item.name} ."-". {item.sku}) }}
```

Also, does anyone know if this automatically adds the dashes and the .html?

Any guidance would be extremely appreciated.

EDIT:

I have successfully tested this as working in my test environment, but it is not working as expected in my production environment.  I'll go over what happens, and what I did.

1) I purged the core_url_rewrite table
2) I deleted all cache
3) I set up MAGMI (updated it to the most current version as well, and triple checked all my settings)
4) MAGMI went through fine, and the url key on about 5 products that I checked for were how I would expect
5) During the catalog url rewrites reindex, all url keys disappeared.
6) After the reindex was done, they were now in the default magento format (using just the name, and not the sku)

Any ideas?

The only difference between production and development that I can think of at the moment that may have anything to do with this is the fact that I did create a module based on the linked manufacturer-in-product-url-key question on production.  Now that I think of it, maybe that's the main difference that I need to address..... I didn't think reindexing would have anything to do with that, but maybe I'm wrong.

Anyway, if anyone has any insight, I would still appreciate it.  I have a feeling maybe MAGMI should also be rewriting the url_path??  I think I read something about that somewhere.

Comment: `{{ Slugger::slug({item.name} ."-". {item.sku}) }}` is correct, that should add the sku to your url_key values.

Comment: This worked fine in my dev site, but with single quotes instead, but not production (doh!)  In my test site, everything worked as expected.  I am using another script called "Dn'D Patch Index URL."  It is installed on both the production environment and the test environment.  The test environment worked perfectly - I reindex and everything, and it goes through as expected.  In the production environment, the url key was listed in each product.  Then, during the rewrites index, it was blank. Now it's the default magento url key. Do I need to set url_path maybe?

Comment: I think I solved it!  I am using a service to update all of my product information -- to grab images, accurate descriptions, the name of products, short description -- all that fun stuff.  The problem is, when this information is over-written, Magento seems to revert back to its default url based on the name of the product.  So, due to this, I am going to have to implement my script.  It's a good lesson learned.  I'll answer my own question in detail.  Is there a way to give you credit on here for part of it Axel?

Comment: No need to give me credit on anything ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  I think this is the best approach.

I was mistaken in my question.  I'm actually looking to add the mpn, not the sku.  Either way, that doesn't change the process.

So, the best thing to do is to use the Value Replacer in MAGMI, and to create a custom module that updates the url on the Magento catalog_product_save_before event.

Here's exactly what I did.....

**MAGMI settings (Value Replacer)**

```
Replaced attributes: url_key
New value for url_key: {{ Slugger::slug({item.name}.' '.{item.mpn}) }}
```

**URLKeyChange (Magento Module)**

*app/code/local/My/URLKeyChange/etc/config.xml*

```
<config>

    <global>

       <models>

           <LeathornURLRewrite>
                <class>Leathorn_URLKeyChange_Model</class>
           </LeathornURLRewrite>

       </models>

            <events>
                <catalog_product_save_before>
                    <observers>
                        <LeathornURLRewrite>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>LeathornURLRewrite/observer</class>
                            <method>updateurl</method>
                        </LeathornURLRewrite>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_save_before>
            </events>
    </global>

</config>
```

*app/code/local/My/URLKeyChange/Model/Observer.php*

```
class My_URLKeyChange_Model_Observer {
    public function updateurl($observer){
        Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');
        if($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()){
            $Product=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $Url='';
            if(!is_null($Product->getData('name'))):
            $Url=$Url.$Product->getData('name');
            endif;
            if(!is_null($Product->getData('mpn'))):
            $Url=$Url.$Product->getData('mpn').'-';
            endif;
            //Mage::log('My log entry'.$Url, null, 'mylogfile.log');
            $Product->setData('url_key',$Url);
        }
    }
}
```

*app/etc/modules/My_URLKeyChange.xml*

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_URLKeyChange>

            <!-- Whether our module is active: true or false -->
            <active>true</active>

            <!-- Which code pool to use: core, community or local -->
            <codePool>local</codePool>

        </My_URLKeyChange>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

URL key will always be just dash separated strings. Don't worry, magento will add .html in it dynamically. You can see in magnento backend in any product configuration page, url key is without html.

Also magento will add dash in url key, Replace your "-" by space " ". Otherwise it will take last word of name and SKU as one word. :)